# King Composer - Textarea Field, Textarea-HTML, Editor Field not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I build a theme for a customer but I face issues with `King Composer` -
the textarea and editor params don't work.

When I add params as textarea or editor it comes nice. But Output Value shows unexpected text.

I added `Description Here in textarea and editor params` But it's showing this text [see screenshot output http://prntscr.com/b66vfs](http://prntscr.com/b66vfs)

Does anyone run into these issues before?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in our plugin.
Your issues solved on some days ago.

Please update to latest version to get that.
See more at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/textarea-field-textarea-html-editor-field-not-working?replies=4